# Swift Array extension with determined Element type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

```
extension Array where Element: StringLiteralConvertible{

    func spliteByPrefix() -> [Element]{

        for item in self{

        }

        return []
    }

}
```

I want to write an extension of Array whose Element is always a String. And in my spliteByPrefix() function, i want to use maybe item.characters or something else which a String has. How?

Answer (score 1):

As for now, you cannot write an extension of `Array` "whose `Element` is always a `String`" in Swift.

But you can write some extension which has nearly the same functionality.

Write your own protocol, which `String` can conform to:

```
protocol MyStringType {
    var characters: String.CharacterView { get }

    //You may need some other properties or methods to write your extension...
}
// Make `String` the only type conforming to `MyStringType`.
extension String: MyStringType {}
```

And write an extension where `Element` conforms to the protocol.

```
extension Array where Element: MyStringType {

    func spliteByPrefix() -> [Element]{ //You really want to return, `Array<Element>`?
        for item in self {
            for ch in item.characters {
                //Do something with `ch`.
                _ = ch
            }
        }
        return []
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example `Element` is always a `Int`. I use the elements themselves of the array

```
extension Array where Element: IntegerType {
    func toString() -> [String] {
        var result = [String]()
        for value in self {
            result.append(String(value))
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
let numberInt = [23, 10, 79, 3]
let numberString = numberInt.toString()
```

Comment: Note that any type can adopt StringLiteralConvertible, see http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/ for some examples.

Comment: Thank @MartinR for your comment, I've updated the code I think StringLiteralConvertible was not a right choice

Comment: Did you check if that compiles?